# Water Systems — when can I use buckets of water to simulate an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, computer-science, mathematical-modeling

It is quite common to use physical systems to perform calculations (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_computing) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconventional_computing)). This is for a number of reasons: sometimes the physical system is efficient, sometimes it helps us understand the general principles of the physical system, and sometimes, because it can be a good way of demonstrating how a formal system works.

In this case, I am interested in the latter case. I want to find a physical system that demonstrates how a system of ODEs works. Specifically, I'm interested in ODEs of a particular form:

$$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t} = \sum_j A_{ij} x_j + B_i$$

I have a specific case in mind, but the general case is interesting. In particular I have been thinking about water models, which can model a subset of these equations, and about which I have some questions (see below).

The following is an instantiation of the system:

$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = A - Bx$$
$$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = Bx - Cy$$

[image]

with appropriately chosen $A\propto a$, $B \propto b$ etc.

Here is another system, choosing the appropriate $k \propto K$ (one can easily add a constant into this by changing the relative heights):

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = k(y-x)$$
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = k(x-y)$$

[image]

**My questions**:

1. Show whether the system $$ \dot{x} = a - bx + cy$$ $$\dot{y} = bx - dy$$ can be instantiated using pumps, taps, and holes (I'm fairly sure it cannot).
2. More generally, using pumps, taps and holes, what are the constraints on $[A_{ij}]$ and $[B_i]$.
3. Assuming that the equation in (1) cannot be instantiated, what physical modification could be used to make it possible. (there are quite a lot of possibilities, for example, [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEY5AgcR2yE))

**So far**:

For 2: The way I'm thinking of going about it is to define a "water system" inductively. Let $\mathcal{W}$ be the set of "water systems", made of a set of differential equations and a logical condition $\mathcal{C}$ under which they apply. This may or may not be correct...

1. The pair containing $n$ diffential equations $\{\dot{x_i} = 0 \;|\; i=1\ldots n\}$ and $\mathcal{C}=T$ is a water system.
2. Joining basins: If $\{\dot{x}_i = f_i(x_1 \ldots x_n)\}\in\mathcal{W}$, then systems transformed by $$f_i\rightarrow f_i + k(x_i - x_j + \Delta h)$$ $$f_j \rightarrow f_j + k(x_j - x_i - \Delta h)$$ $$C \rightarrow C \wedge (something??) $$ also belongs to $\mathcal{W}$.
3. Leaks: If $\{\dot{x}_i = f_i(x_1 \ldots x_n)\}\in\mathcal{W}$, then systems transformed by $f_i\rightarrow f_i - k(x_i - h)$ is also in $\mathcal{W}$.
4. Other stuff

Anyway, not sure this is the right way of going about it.

Comment: An other related physical system to consider (I don't know if you're interested in this or not, but here goes) is to have a set of tanks each with an amount and concentration of something dissolved in water (usually table salt; salt water is a solution everyone's familiar with). Then add pumps to move water between the tanks, taking care that each tank recieves as much as it loses. Then let $x_i$ be the concentration (or total amount) of the solute in each tank (assuming that the pipes have no capacity and each tank is perfectly mixed at all times).

Comment: The flow through an opening goes as the square root of the pressure differential across it.  You can just decree that your physics are different from the real world, or change the shape of your tanks.  I don't think it changes the interesting points of the question.

Comment: I don't think changing the tank shape helps.

Comment: @RossMillikan There seems to be a difference between laminar flow and turbulent flow. One is linear, the other square root, in pressure difference. Why is the turbulent flow more relevant? (empirically it seems to be)

Comment: I think because most flow, particularly at high pressure differentials, is turbulent.  My idea of changing the tank shape was to have the height in the tank proportional to the square of the contents, so you make the pressure follow that curve.  The area would have to be proportional to the inverse square root of the depth.

Comment: @RossMillikan I've just been watching youtube videos of guys making laminar nozzles - seems a way of linearising the system is theoretically possible, though not very practical. I think pressure depends on the mass above, not on the height (the forumula $p=\rho g h$ is derived from $p=g \rho V / A = mg/A = F/A$), this means that changing the shape will make the height to flow ratio correct, the amount of mass/volume needed to change the height will not be linear with the flow it creates - and that's what matters.

Comment: The quantity at the inlet to the orifice is the pressure-it doesn't know about the mass above.  If you multiply the area by a large factor ( by changing the base area of the tank), the mass above increases by that factor, but the pressure doesn't and the flow doesn't either.

Comment: @RossMillikan At constant density, if you increase the area you increase the mass proportionally, so I agree that the pressure stays the same - with straight sided vessels there is no way to tease apart the contribution of mass and height. But I disagree that it doesn't know about the mass above - otherwise the pressure would not depend on the density of the liquid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have something for question 1. It has to be divided into two cases: $c<d$ and $c>d$.

If $c<d$, then going from your first picture, you open up another hole in the bottom tank, with width $d-c$. You rerout the $c$-stream directly (or if you like your gravity working predictably, via another reservoir and a high-prerformance pump capable of keeping said reservoir dry) to the upper tank, and you let the $d-c$ go into the reservoir.

If $c>d$, you're in trouble, because then the $cy$ water that enters the upper tank would be more than the $dy$ water leaving the lower. I believe that this scenario is impossible without sensors and automaticly adjusting pumps and holes (trying to output the difference through pump $a$, for instance), and that defeats the whole idea if using tanks and pumps to make it easier to visualize.

Comment: That suggestion could work. Basically, you can get $c<d$ in the limit of the pump being infinitely fast, eh?

Comment: @Lucas Yes. As well as the water falling from one tank to another not taking any time at all to get there, and there being no friction in the hole opening, and I'm sure a few other minor details. You have to make simplifying (and not practically attainable) assumptions like that in order to construct a physical scenario from such simple equations.